# Dynamically create textbox rotated by 180 degrees

Tags: ms-word, textbox, rotation, docx4j

I would like to create a Word document with multiple text boxes that serve as name badges. Each name appears twice, once set normally and once rotated by 180 degrees. Later, they are printed on paper, cut and folded, so they can stand on a table.

I am using docx4j to generate the DOCX file. My idea is to have a **fragment** in one Word file that serves as a template **for a single name badge**. I'd like to load that template and fill the placeholders with real names. Multiple fragments are then concatenated and written to a second Word template, so ultimately I have a list with multiple name badges. The paper I use allows two name badges on each page (i.e. four text boxes).

However, I fail implementing this with docxj4. This is what I tried:

(1) First, I tried filling a single name badge. The placeholders got filled correctly, but the rotated text box of my Word template (input) became an ordinary (not rotated) text box in the output file.

(2) I also tried `MainDocumentPart#addParagraph(String)` and created the entire paragraph myself, using XML code generated in Word (where the text box was rotated). The output generated by docx4j, however, again did not respect the rotation. It created two text boxes, but when I view them in Word now, I even cannot rotate them there anymore. It seems like the generated text boxes are different from those created by Word in the first place.

**Long story short, how can I create a rotated text box with docx4j?**

It would be very convenient, if I could have a Word template to layout the name badges, but if I would have to create the entire thing programatically, it would be fine, too. Also, other ways of rotating text would be okay for me. But it seems like text boxes are the only objects in Word that can actually be rotated by 180 degrees.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem.  You might also be able to do this with WordArt, or a suitable shape.  These amount to much the same thing.  To make it easy on yourself, you need to anchor to a paragraph not the page.  If you post your template somewhere, I'll see if I can help.

Comment: But it should work with text boxes in docx4j as well? I uploaded my templates here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f1c491a5064004b822ea988ee48096f020171027080518/455f40

Comment: @JasonPlutext: Did you have a chance to check my templates? The download expires after 7 days. Please let me know, if you encounter any problems.

Comment: I've downloaded it, but haven't had a chance to check yet.  Hopefully later today.

Comment: Meanwhile, I managed to create a flipped textbox by manually providing XML code. In my first approach there was a ``mcChoice`` element in the code, which caused the box not to flip. Now that I only have a ``w:drawing`` and removed the ``mc:Fallback`` branch, at least the flipping works. I'd still favor re-using a textbox fragment that is defined in a Word sub-template, though. Coding the entire XML code myself seems suboptimal.

Comment: My DOCX document looks fine on screen in Word now. When I print it or do a PDF export, however, the flipped textbox will not be rotated by 180 degrees in the output. :-( So the ``w:drawing`` on its own does not work.

Comment: Me again. Managed to rotate the content of a textbox in both Word and PDF now. There are actually two possibilities to rotate text in Word: (1) Rotate the box with the green dot that is shown on one edge of the box. (2) Flip it with an option in the menu bar. These features will result in different XML code. Rotating works in PDF, too, whereas flipping only works in DOCX. I'll update my original post with my findings soon.

Comment: Good detective work :-)